# TextView.setText in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android development and I want to understand how TextView.setText method works. In this example,

```
private TrueFalse[] mQuestionBank = new TrueFalse[]
        {
                new TrueFalse(R.string.question_oceans, true),
                new TrueFalse(R.string.question_mideast, false),
                new TrueFalse(R.string.question_africa, false),
        };

private  int mCurrentIndex = 0;
mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
```

The point I can't understand is how can setText return question text by only getting an int? How can an int be sufficient? Could you explain that to me? Thanks.

Comment: the `int` is an entry of strings.xml, `R.string.question_oceans` for instance.

Comment: @Blackbelt so setText searches in R.java file and finds the string and prints it?

Comment: not really. It asks for the string to the `AssetManager`.  R.java contains only the definition of the ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

int here, is the id of String value which defined in the string.xml. So textView.setText(int resid) get value as string then set internally.

Here's the source code of TextView.

```
public final void setText(CharSequence text) {
        setText(text, mBufferType);
}

// So this get string value from resources and use the above setText().
public final void setText(int resid) {
    setText(getContext().getResources().getText(resid));
}
```

You can avoid getting string value from resources and make your code simpler.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a String to the String files it generate a reference in the R file and this reference is a int and it can be used on the code and in the xml file like:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/question_oceans" />
```

The reference of the String "R.string.question_oceans" in the R file is an int, so SetText can accept int (from the reference) and can accept a real Strings like "my string".